# How to convert a text into double in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I used the following way to change the string into double but unfortunately this closes the app. The EditText inputtype is "NumberDecimal"

```
numA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numA);
numB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numB);

//App forceclose here. Not sure why.
final Double a = Double.parseDouble(numA.getText().toString());
final Double b = Double.parseDouble(numB.getText().toString());

calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         numLS.setText("" + ( (- (Double) b) /(2 * (Double) a)));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
          String s = b.getText().toString();  
          final double a = Double.valueOf(s.trim()).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Look up [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Answer (score 3):

Perform this check:

```
if (!numA.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    final Double a = Double.parseDouble(numA.getText().toString());
}

if (!numB.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    final Double b = Double.parseDouble(numB.getText().toString());
}
```

An empty string argument to Double.parseDouble() produces a `NumberFormatException`.

As a suggestion, if you are working on making a calculator(or converter), you should add more checks for invalid input. For example, you should add a check for when the user inputs just the decimal point(.) or input of form (3.).

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use a try catch because other unparseable data will throw an exception and it may not be the best to rely on the UI to force valid numbers only.

```
numA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numA);
numB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numB);

Double a;
Double b;
try {
    a = Double.parseDouble(numA.getText().toString());
    b = Double.parseDouble(numB.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();
    a = 0.0;
    b = 0.0;
}

final double aFin = a;
final double bFin = b;
calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //Also, you used your class as an onClickListener you would have to make your doubles final.

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         numLS.setText("" + ( (- (Double) b) /(2 * (Double) a)));
         //Division by zero will produce a NaN you should probably check user input data sanity
    }
});
```